# Question about Ka in Book 7

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

Not sure if this is spoiler worthy, so I'll err on the side of caution and make it hidden.

> Towards the middle/end of the book, once they are within the White Lands of Empathica, they are said to be 'beyond Ka.'

How can this be, and what does it mean?

Comment: Ka is life-force. In the Dark Tower series it typically means fate or destiny, a force that is neither good nor evil, but that drives life and death. "Beyond Ka" simply means to be beyond destiny, or having accomplished something beyond means. Beyond the looking glass so to say.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: that sounds more like an answer than a comment ;)

Comment: As you wish....

Comment: I addition to the above, I always took it to mean that the Towers efforts at Dandelos house were the last direct influence that the Tower intended to make on Rolands journey.  After that, everything else (most specifically dealing with Mordred and Los) were completely up to Roland and the remains of his Ka-tet.  Perhaps the Tower cannot influence areas near it (similar to the large sailing ships of the 16th-19th centuries).  The Tower has guided his Ka to that point, and the rest was his to perform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ka is life-force. In the Dark Tower series it typically means fate or destiny, a force that is neither good nor evil, but that drives life and death. "Beyond Ka" simply means to be beyond destiny, or having accomplished something beyond means. Beyond the looking glass so to speak.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the passage you are talking about:

> “We’re just asking, not trying to convince you,” Fimalo said. “But the truth is bald: now this is only your quest, gunslinger. That’s all it is. Nothing sends you further. **Once you pass beyond this castle and into the White Lands, you and your friends pass beyond ka itself**. And you need not do it. **All you have been through was set in motion so that you might save the Beams, and by saving them ensure the eternal existence of the Tower, the axle upon which all worlds and all life spins. That is done. If you turn back now, the dead King will be trapped forever where he is.**”
>   -  *The Dark Tower:  Book VII:  The Dark Tower*

The idea is that Ka only planned for Roland to save the Beams, which he has already done.  The only reason Roland has for continuing on to the tower itself is his own vanity and obsession.  Ka has nothing to do with that.  Ka wanted Roland to save the universes, and he has.  Ka isn't interested in his obsession with climbing the tower;  that's just Roland being vainglorious.

And the Crimson King is now trapped outside the tower, and cannot enter it because he has no sigul of Eld;  Roland has two siguls of Eld on his person (his guns).  Thus, by approaching the tower, Roland is bringing the very thing the Crimson King needs to destroy the tower within the Crimson King's reach.  This is a very dangerous prospect, and being beyond Ka, there is no way to predict how it will work out.

More importantly, let's look at what happens next.  The three Stephen Kings had brought baskets of food and warm clothing to Roland and Susannah.  The gunslingers refuse to take the gifts, and walk away.  Then:

> She suddenly understood what the gunslinger must have known, if not from the first then from soon after the three Stephen Kings appeared: this whole thing was a shuck. She didn’t know what, exactly, was in those wicker baskets, but she doubted like hell that it was food and clothes.
>
> She and Roland began to turn away.  And that was when Feemalo and Fumalo, still down on their knees, reached inside the open baskets before them. Susannah needed no instruction from Roland, not so much as a shouted word. She drew the revolver from her belt and shot down the one on her left—Fumalo—just as he swung a long-barreled silver gun out of the basket. What looked like a scarf was hanging from it. Roland drew from his holster, as blindingly fast as ever, and fired a single shot. Above them the rooks took wing, cawing affrightedly, turning the blue sky momentarily black. Feemalo, also holding one of the silver guns, collapsed slowly forward across his basket of food with a dying expression of surprise on his face and a bullet-hole dead center in his forehead.
>   - *ibid*

It turns out, these three Stephen King lookalikes claiming to be shape shifters were actually apparitions created by the Crimson King's Minister of State.  The whole point was to stop Roland, Susannah, and Oy.  Nothing they said can be trusted, so their "beyond Ka" claims may well have been absolute nonsense.

Yes, after he's caught, the Minister of State fesses up to his crimes, and says he didn't lie to the gunslingers, but who the hell is stupid enough to believe someone who says "okay, you caught me in a lie, but everything else I said was true, I swear!"?

Finally, Susannah later realizes that there is no such thing as "beyond Ka":

> And the voice inside — that deep voice — whispered: *Four nights. Four nights to dream.  That should be enough. Maybe more than enough*. **Of course, ka would have to intervene. If they had indeed outrun its influence, that wouldn’t — *couldn’t* — happen. But Susannah now thought ka reached everywhere, even to the Dark Tower. Was, perhaps, embodied by the Dark Tower.**
>   - *ibid*;  italics in original, bold mine.

And later still, within sight of the tower itself, Roland comes to the same conclusion:

> An odd certainty came to Roland then: the thorns of these roses only pricked when their roots still tied the plant to Mim, or Mother Earth. Had he gotten his way with Patrick, Mim would have cut those talented hands to ribbons and rendered them useless.
>
> ***It’s still ka, the gunslinger thought. Even out here in End-W[orld]***
>   -  *ibid*